# Socket connection android to iphone

Tags: android, ios, sockets

i'm developing a small example about socket connection between android and ios (via wifi), after trying, the connection hasn't been established. Here is what I have done so far, I created a server on ios (used Bonjour to publish the service). I also created a client on android. However, after starting the server on ios, I also got the log:

```
ServerSocketConnection[3487:c07] Bonjour Service Published: domain(local.) type(_serversocket._tcp.) name(Macmini) port(54065)
```

Which means the server starting ok.

To the client part(android), I created the client through `Socket` class, some few lines of code:

```
Socket s = new Socket("local.", 54065);
OutputStream out = s.getOutputStream();
PrintWriter output = new PrintWriter(out);
output.println("Hello Android!");
BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(s.getInputStream()));
String st = input.readLine();
```

Putting it into AsyncTask to execute. However, I got the `UnknowHostException`:

```
08-06 12:45:44.460: W/System.err(873): java.net.UnknownHostException: Unable to resolve host "local.": No address associated with hostname
```

I'm a newbie to this kind of problem so any ideas what the problem is? I know it's related to the "host" thing but need the way to fix it. 
*Note: I run 2 apps on 2 simulators (ios and android) as the same wifi network and same MAC, maybe this is the problem? any help would be appreciated and sorry for my English, it's not my native one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the actual IP address of the iPhone instead of 'local.'.

On Android you can find a phone's IP via Settings -> WiFi -> Advanced.  Not sure if iPhone offers the same option.

ps. Also be sure to have the internet permission in your manifest;

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, that's right, I used the actual IP address, in this case the machine address and it connects perfectly.